# What unit is used in CPU metric in GKE deployment overview?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, resources, google-kubernetes-engine, cpu, metrics

In GCP when I want to see the resource usage of a pod I see this in the CPU graph:
[image]

What kind of unit is "9.6e-3" and how does this value relate to mCPU?

Comment: As per this [doc](https://docs.cloudlinux.com/command-line_tools/#lveinfo) mCPU means max CPU usage is i.e 9.6e-3 = 9.6 x 10-3 = 0.0096 (Convert to Real Number) Max is the peak usage hit during a specific time span. I think the CPU was pick hit for 0.0096 seconds

Comment: @Mahboob
Ah ok so it's a 9.6 exponent minus 3 calculation.
In some cases it shows 0.001 which proves your point. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

As per this [doc](https://docs.cloudlinux.com/command-line_tools/#lveinfo) mCPU means max CPU usage is i.e 9.6e-3 = 9.6 x 10-3 = 0.0096 (Convert to Real Number) Max is the peak usage hit during a specific time span. I think the CPU was pick hit for 0.0096 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that they have fixed this recently.
[image]